# Sorting a list alphabetically, whilst maintaining previous index

Tags: python, sorting

I have a personal project in which I have a list of name's and 3 scores corresponding to a certain name. However, I would like to 'sort' this list into alphabetical order, whilst maintaining the previous index so that I could link the score's.
What I would like to achieve is being able to sort this list into alphabetical order, and print the score(s) corresponding to the name, I do not see how I can make this more concise and informative.

Here is some of my code:

```
Names = ['Fred', 'John', 'Sally']
Scores = [1,5,9,2,4,6,3,6,5]
for i in range(0, len(Names)):
    print("The score(s) for", Names[i], "is:", Scores[i], Scores[i+3], Scores[i+6])`
```

Therefore, for example, my preferred result for this program, when sorted, would be:

> The score(s) for John is: 5, 4, 6 
>   etc...

Comment: This makes no sence to me, plus i dont know python, but why dont you use objects or some kind of structure (u guess they exist in python) you could have a String and an array of ints under there and use them together

Comment: it is better if you store each person and its relevant scores in a dict. like:
{"John":[2,4,6]}

Comment: Is this your GCSE exam coursework?

Comment: From your description I don't really understand what your data means or what problem you're trying to solve. How do the three names in the list of names relate to the nine scores? What is the rest of the output you expect? It sounds like you expect John to be output first, but I can't see a reason for it to sort before Fred.

Comment: @DNA no this is not relating to GCSE coursework

Answer (score 1):

If you're assuming every name is unique, this can be pretty fast forward. You just need to use the index from the unsorted list.

```
names = ['Fred', 'John', 'Sally', 'Alex']
scores = [1,5,9,7, 2,4,6,8, 3,6,5,9]

l = len(names)
for e in sorted(names):
    i = names.index(e) # index in unsorted list
    print "The score for", e, "is:", scores[i], scores[i+l], scores[i+2*l]
```

Comment: I commend you my fellow Python-er, I had no idea that this task could be tackled with such ease; you provided the most efficient answer for my program in this scenario, and I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of arbitrary `list`s is the wrong data structure to use here. Create a dictionary with a key of the user's name and a value of their list of scores. If you have to start with the given `Names` and `Scores`, here's how that's done:

```
>>> Names=['Fred', 'John', 'Sally']
>>> Scores=[1,5,9,2,4,6,3,6,5]
>>> Scores = [Scores[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(Scores), 3)]
>>> all_scores = {k:v for k,v in zip(Names, Scores)}
>>> all_scores
{'Sally': [3, 6, 5], 'John': [2, 4, 6], 'Fred': [1, 5, 9]}
```

Now you can `sort` and `print` that dictionary however you like.

Answer (score 0):

First start by rearranging your data model, like this:

```
Names = ['Fred', 'John', 'Sally']
Scores = [1,5,9,2,4,6,3,6,5]

data = {}
for index, name in enumerate(Names):
    data[name] = [Scores[(index * 3)], Scores[(index * 3) + 1], Scores[(index * 3) + 2]]
```

now `data` contains:

```
{'John': [2, 4, 6], 'Sally': [3, 6, 5], 'Fred': [1, 5, 9]}
```

now you can do whatever you want. to print the names and scores in sorted manner you can:

```
for name in sorted(data.keys()):
    print name, date[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should make a new list of indices, and sort that new list.

```
ordered_name_list = range(len(names))
ordered_name_list.sort(key=lambda item: name[item])
```

Then, use that ordered name list to pick each name and each offset into Scores. Your list accessing is really unpythonic, too.

```
for o in ordered_name_list:
    print("The scores for {0} are {1}".format(names[o], ", ".join(Scores[o::3])))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is **very** un-pythonic for many reasons.

First of all, just a small thing, you don't want to ever use `range(len())`. Use enumerate instead as such: `for i, val in enumerate(Names):`, so you'll get both the index and the value.

Now to your actual problem. You shouldn't be storing the values like that in two separate lists. This is exactly what dictionaries were made for:

```
scores={"Fred": [1, 2, 3], "John": [5, 4, 6], "Sally": [9, 6, 5]}
```

Of course, dictionaries can't be sorted since they have no order, so you have to ues [OrderedDicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). These are dictionaries that preserve order.

So here's what you should be doing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

scores={"Fred": [1, 2, 3], "John": [5, 4, 6], "Sally": [9, 6, 5]}
scores=OrderedDict(sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Voila! And to print it:

```
for name, score in scores.items():
    print("The scores for {0} are {1}, {2}, and {3}.".format(name, *score))
```

Comment: Dictionaries can't be sorted, but they can be iterated over in a sorted fashion with `sorted(my_dictionary)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 True, but this is exactly what OrderedDicts were made for. Look at the documentation for OrderedDicts. The first example they give is about sorting dicts.

Comment: I just don't want people to think that they absolutely must use `OrderedDict` any time they want to print out a dictionary according to some sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changing your nick, I would suggest:

```
# rearrange into a list of tuples with (name, [scores]) structure
data = [(name, Scores[idx*3:idx*3+3]) for (idx,name) in enumerate(Names)]

# then sort alphabetically on name
import operator
data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [Scores[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(Scores), 3)]
print sorted([(name, all_scores) for name, all_scores in zip(Names, zip(*scores))])
```